# Map 3D point cloud onto surface then flatten

Tags: dictionary, 3d, projection, flatten, topography

Mapping a point cloud onto a 3D "fabric" then flattening.

So I have a scientific dataset consisting of a point cloud in 3D, this point cloud comprises points on a surface that is curved. In order to perform quantitative analysis I however need to map these point clouds onto a surface I can then flatten. I thought about using mapping tools sort of like in the case of the 3d world being flattened onto a map, but not sure how to even begin as I have no experience in cartography and maybe I'm trying to solve an easy problem with the wrong tools.

Just to briefly describe the dataset: imagine entirely transparent curtains on the window with small dots on them, if I could use that dot pattern to fit the material the dots are on I could then "straighten" it and do meaningful analysis on the spread of the dots. I'm guessing the procedure would be to first manually fit the "sheet" onto the point cloud data by using contours or something along those lines then flattening the sheet thus putting the points into a 2d array. Ultimately I'll probably also reduce that into a 1D but I assume I need the intermediate 2D step as the length of the 2nd dimension is variable (i.e. one end of the sheet is shorter than the other but still corresponds to the same position in terms of contours) I'm using Matlab and Amira though I'm always happy to learn new tools!

Any advice or hints how to approach are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a space filling curve to reduce the 3d complexity to a 1d complexity. I use a hilbert curve to index lat-lng pairs on a 2d map. You can do the same with a 3d space but it's easier to start with a simple curve for example a z morton order curve. Space filling curves are often used in mapping applications. A space filling curve also adds some proximity information and a new sort order to the 3d points.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build a surface that approximates your dataset, then unfold the surface with the points you want. [Solid3dtech.com](http://Solid3dtech.com) has the tool to unfold the surfaces with the curves or points.